# Change jenkins root configuration config.xml location

Tags: jenkins

I am setting up a customized Jenkins. My jenkins home is

```
echo $JENKINS_HOME
/srv/jenkins
```

This means that the location of my `config.xml` file is

```
$JENKINS_HOME/config.xml
/srv/jenkins/config.xml
```

But I want Jenkins to read the `config.xml` file from under

```
$$JENKINS_HOME/config/config.xml
/srv/jenkins/config/config.xml
```

You might ask why ? Because since this is a customized Jenkins, Im am deploying the `config.xml` file on runtime in a Helm chart on Kubernetes and this file will change based on the customization by different teams. And I want this file to persist after Ive done the modification during the `InitContainer` phase of my pod startup.

One thing I tried was to create a softlink

```
jenkins@25bea2ece6a9:~$ cd /srv/jenkins/
jenkins@25bea2ece6a9:~$ ls -ltrh | grep config.xml
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jenkins root      30 Nov 23 16:01 config.xml -> /srv/jenkins/config/config.xml
```

When I startup the Pod, this link is present but within 10 seconds, Jenkins overwrites this link with an actual file and all my configurations are overwirtten.

So can I tell jenkins to read the `config.xml` file from somewhere else ?

Comment: You can use the [configuration as code plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuration+as+Code+Plugin) to inject your configuration at run time instead

Answer (score 0):

No, config.xml is hardcoded in source and until you want to recompile Jenkins by yourself this cannot be done. config.xml is written and by jenkins when loaded.

Great people working on Configuration as Code plugin want to bring this philosophy to jenkins but until it's stable (and it's not currently) you have to use init.groovy scripts for automation.

Jenkins currently provides access to it's initialization through groovy hooks (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Hook+Script)

And what you can do is write init.groovy script which can issue reload on copied config.

You can do that using initialization state:

```
import hudson.init.InitMilestone

if(Jenkins.instance.getInitLevel() == InitMilestone.COMPLETED){
  // copy config.xml
  Jenkins.instance.reload()
} else { 
  // sleep for a while, do some other stuff
}
```